# Unexpected gap between CSS header elements

Tags: html, css

I'm currently redesigning a website and have run into an issue with some elements in the header. The header contains a logo, some text and a navigation bar. Between the bottom of the logo and the top of the navigation bar there is a relatively thick gap, shown in this screenshot:

[image: Problem]

I don't want the gap, I don't know where it's come from and I don't know how to get rid of it :(

I can reduce it down to a single pixel by setting the `line-height` property of the div containing the logo down to `0.0`, but it seems hacky and still doesn't fix the issue.

The work-in-progress version can be viewed live [here](http://sandbox.woodstockdesigns.co.uk/), if anyone with more HTML/CSS experience can identify any silly mistakes I've made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following css class

```
.logo img
{
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: This one is the best solution.

Comment: This too reduces the gap to a single black pixel. Where's the stray pixel coming from? :)

Comment: use .openingtimes p{margin:0;}

Answer (score 3):

The space comes from descenders which allow `y` and `g` characters to fully fit vertically.
`display:block;` or `vertical-align:bottom;` should equally work.

Comment: Thanks; that works much better, but there is still a single pixel gap :/

Comment: That's coming from the paragraph. Set a `line-height:1` on `.openingtimes p`

Answer (score 2):

```
img { display: block; }
```

The gap is there because images are inline elements aligned at the text baseline by default. It's where [descenders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) would go if you had text with descenders in the same line.

Comment: Thanks; that works much better, but there is still a single pixel gap :/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're getting some spacing from both the `<div class="logo">`, and from the `<a href="#">` which wrap your logo.  You can fix this using the `display:block;` or `vertical-align:bottom;` as mentioned above.

---

**Recommendation:** If you're not currently using it, you might want to look at installing the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for Firefox.  It's a great tool for inspecting your page.  You can highlight specific areas, and Firebug will show you which HTML elements and CSS classes are responsible for the layout.

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` containing the element should have `display:block; position:relative` and the image should have `position:absolute`. Works here.